# PHP mail and array: Only appears "Array" in the field Para: (To: in english)

Tags: php

I have a question (error) in my code. Please, can you help me? I explain to you. I have a table called users with a column called email_users. I want put all the emails to send but only appers "Para:Array". The others fields work fine.

```
    <?php
        $result = mysqli_query("SELECT email_users FROM users");

        $para=array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $para[]=$row['email_users'];
        }


        cabeceras....

        mail(implode(',', $para), $asunto, $mensaje, $cabeceras);

    ?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your $para array is multidimensional array. You should try this in while loop instead of $para[] = $row["emailhttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage_users"].

```
array_push($para, $row["email_users"];
```

Also, you can't send multi emails with mail function like that. You must use foreach for all mails. For example

```
foreach ($para as $singleMail) {       
   mail ($singleMail, $asunto, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
}
```

From PHP documentation mail function explained.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Yes, is the same result as it says Ivor Hort. Para:Array

Comment: Yes, my fault. I saw now, with implode you are getting all emails and put this in mail function, but this can't be done in that way, mail function can be used for one email address in one time.

Comment: Any improvement ?

Comment: No, Ivor Hort. There haven´t way to print the emails.

Answer (score 0):

In this moment I'm here. The solution is with foreach but need more help. (Thanks Ivor Hort)

```
<?php

include 'functions.php';  
$con_db= connect_db("localhost", "root", "");
$con_db= select_db($con_db, "offers");


$result=mysqli_query($con_db,"SELECT email_users FROM users");
$para=array($result);

foreach($para as $valor){
    var_dump($para) ."\n";
}

?>
```

But now my problem is here. This appears with var_dump. I tried with print_r and echo but anyone works. This method is to check if the mails are saved as strings but the result isn't as expected.

array(1) { [0]=> object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(6) ["type"]=> int(0) } }

I'm very lost in this moment. I don´t know why the emails don´t save in the array...

Thanks and sorry for the inconvenient.

Edit:

Finally, I found the solution:

```
    <?php

    include 'functions.php';  
    $con_db= connect_db("localhost", "root", "");
    $con_db= select_db($con_db, "offers");

        $result=mysqli_query($con_db,"SELECT email_users FROM users");
        $para=array();

        while($row=$sql->fetch_assoc()){
            mail($row['email_users'],$asunto,$mensaje,$cabeceras);}

?>
```

With this code, php mail send one email to every user and not have any problem.